# On Dold fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology

The article of nLab on [Dold fibration](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dold+fibration)

I have two questions:

1. How to construct Dold fibration ?   Just like Hurewicz fibration, Hurewicz fibration has a theorem: A map $\pi:E \to B$ is a Hurewicz fibration iff there exists at least one Hurewicz connection for $\pi_!$.
2. Please reference some good readings to me on Dold fibration.